# Cannot login to stackexchange with firefox

Tags: firefox, authentication, openid

I'm having Problem logging in when I open any stackexchange website via Mozilla Firefox.
I use my yahoo login, so when my yahoo account is logged in, I should automatically logged in to stackexchange. So when I open stackoverflow for example, it recognizes me (a message appears on top of the page saying: "**Hello Ashkan, Welcome back...**), when click the message to log in, it refreshes the page but I'm not logged in.
Now I'm using chrome to post this question and it works fine.

I don't know it may be a silly mistake, but I'm having this problem for about 2 or 3 months, since Firefox is my favorite browser it's a little annoying to open chrome separately to search for questions on stackoverflow and etc.

Comment: Do you have any privacy/script/anti-XSS plugins installed or do you disallow cookies from third-parties in your settings?

Comment: the only plugin that concerns this I think is adBlock that I have installed

Comment: I was going to post this question on meta, I'm a little sleepy right now, I posted here by mistake

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Meta.

Comment: @Ani: As I said in the comment above, this was posted by mistake, So I requested to close the question immediately because it's off topic. You can do that too. thnx.

Comment: @Ashkin: Yes, that was an auto-generated comment! They should really mark those as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I deleted cookies for stackoverflow.com and stackexchange.com, and the problem went away. The instructions to delete cookies for specific websites is available [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-cookies-remove-info-websites-stored). I don't know why this happened, but this solution worked for me.

Comment: I followed these instructions and still cannot log onto stackexchange. This is on a new Mac running a fresh install of Mavericks, FF 26.0 and no plug ins. Little Snitch is reporting no blocks to FF.

Comment: Update: after doing it again and restarting FF, the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem and i did all that without a good result But i have found a way around. Under this answer was a link to connect to stackoverflow with facebook. I clicked on that link, it could not connect me but i just clicked on back and i am connected. Hope this will help someone out there.